# Some Objects are Grey in Rendered View

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, 3d-view

I'm newish to Blender and am making a dark Halloween scene. Basically I have distributed a bunch of trees using a particle system, and they are textured and look completely fine in Material Preview view:[image]

But whenever I switch to rendered view (cycles), the trees turn grey and look like this: [image]

Does anyone know what's going on or how to fix it?

Here's the .blend file if it helps:

Comment: Can you just send the screenshot of the nodes that you used for your trees? Have you just assigned a texture of tree from online or have you made the texture by yourself in blender using the nodes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When making the texture using nodes I accidentally set it as a grey emit material in the Principled BSDF Shader.

With all the other nodes going on, I just didn't realize. To fix it I obviously just set the emission strength to zero.